# Help in query for list links

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

How to make one query for display a list of links like this:

Date 05/20/2012
Category - Link
Category - Link
Category - Link
Category - Link
Category - Link

Date 05/19/2012
Category - Link
Category - Link
Category - Link
Category - Link
Category - Link

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$dates = array(); // declare an array to hold dates

echo '<ul>';

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    $thisday = get_the_time('m/d/Y'); // this post's date

if (!in_array($thisday,$dates)) { // check if it's in the array
    echo '<h5>Date '.$thisday.'</h5>'; // if not, print header with date
    $dates[] = $thisday; // and store it
}

echo '<li>';
the_category();
echo '</li>';

endwhile;
endif;

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks moraleida, this works great. Was that i wanted, so much thanks.